# finding an integral manifold of a distribution

Tags: differential-geometry

I have vector fields $\begin{cases}X_1 &=& -y\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+x\frac{\partial}{\partial y},\\ Y &=& (x-y)z\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + (x+y)z \frac{\partial}{\partial y} + (1+z^2) \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\end{cases}$

I have shown that they are commutative and linearly independent, unless  $x=y=0$, so they do span a two dimensional distribution, call it $D$. But how to find its integral surface is a problem.

Comment: Why you didn't accept any answer to your questions? Really, no one answered you correctly? After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first one compute a one form $\omega$ such that $ker \omega =D$. if $\omega =adx=bdy+cdz$, one finds :
$-ay+bx=0, (x-y)za+(x+y)zb+c(1+z^2)=0$. A first solution is $a=x,b=y, c= {z((x^2+y^2)\over 1+z^2}$. A second solution, more efficient is $\omega '= {xdx+ydy\over x^2+y^2}+ {zd z\over 1+z^2}= 2d {\ln(x^2+y^2)+\ln(1+z^2)}= 2d \ln({x^2+y^2\over 1+z^2}) $. And the family of hyperboloids $x^2+y^2=c(1+z^2)$ is tangent to $D$.